# ImportError: No module named RDT

Tags: python, pycharm

Whether or not this question has been asked before, I apologize. Currently taking a networking class and can't run this RDT python program because modules aren't being imported even though everything is there. 
[image: PyCharm Program]

the instructions from the professor are to run the program and record the results. Program won't run because of this error statement.

`ImportError: No module named RTD` even though you can clearly see everything is organized and right there. I don't understand why I am having an issue with this. Help? Thanks!

**EDIT 1** (Added the import statement)

Import Statement: `from RDT import *`

Comment: How are you importing RTD ? Can you post some code ?

Comment: @Jarvis just added the import statement. All of the code is has been set up and written by the professor (I am assuming it's right because he didnt tell us to change anything)

Comment: I think the module RDT is not installed properly, did you try other ways like `import RDT` ?

Comment: I did try that. Same error lol. The whole group of file came in as a zip. I unzipped the folder and opened the folder in pycharm. Is there something I didnt do correctly when I added the folder? @Jarvis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this same problem when I renamed some packages on my Python projects on PyCharm. Looking at you file structure, seems like you have several Python projects under the `GBN/RDT` directory since there are some .idea directories within each folder and if everything was a single project, there should be some `__init__.py` files on each folder indicating they are **Python packages**.

If this is the case, try making PyCharm **aware** that you have several **source directories** (e.g., PR3R, RDT, etc...)

So proceed with the following steps:

1. Right-click over one of the sources directories, say, PR3R.
2. On the dropdown menu, go to **Mark directory as**
3. Select **Sources roots**

Try to execute `RDT.py` again. I assume you want to execute the script.
Repeat this process to the other projects.

**However...** If you want to import something from one module to another module (e.g. import function `foo` from `Receiver.py` in `RDT.py`), you have to:

1. Mark `RDT` (child of GBN) as **Sources roots** (as I explained previously)
2. Add `__init__.py` (which is an empty file that Python uses to know that a given directoy is a package of modules) within RDT and in each child directory (e.g., PR3R, PR3S, and so on....)

Comment: You just saved me 200 points in this haha. Thank you so much 

Comment: thanks mate :) could you kindly upvote my answer too? good luck with your assignment :)

Comment: just upvoted it and marked your answer as correct. Once again, thank you!